# The menu slips in HTML

Tags: html, css

when over menu the menu slips in HTML.

Codes and view:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XvrJpx

Demo:

```css
.menuu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuu ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.menuu>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.menuu>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menuu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.menuu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.menuu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.menuu ul li ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menuu>ul>li>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.icerik {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Anasayfa</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">c</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">c1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">a</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Programlama</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Android</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          Java
        </li>
        <li>
          Php
        </li>
        <li>
          Html
        </li>
        <li>
          Css
        </li>
        <li>
          Javascript
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Turizm</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Origami</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Bebek</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Bebeklerin Aylık Gelişimi</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="iletisim.php">İletişim</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="icerik">Önceden İçerik Aşağı kayıyordu email de dediğiniz gibi projeme position absolute ekledim kaymıyor. Teşekkür ederim. Şimdi Tek sorun Bebek Bölümü ve C bölümü üstüne gelince yana kayıyorlar ve yanındakini de kaydırıyorlar</div>
```

Menu C and menu Bebek have submenu. When over menu the menu slips. I doesn’t would slip.

How I can resolve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: please add your code and all relevant information here directly and avoid redirecting us to other websites. Also, how is this related to android?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I edited question. I can’t get the code in mobile and I can’t access to PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is remove the browsers default `ul` styles, as it is adding 40px of padding to the left, and position the sub-menu items absolutely.
In your case, this will work:

```
ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

To make the sub-menu easier to read, I would recommend having a background and some sort of border. eg:

```
ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `> ul` from

```
.menuu li:hover {
      display: block;
    }
```

so that menu doesnt slip
Hope this is what you need

```css
.menuu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menuu ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.menuu>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.menuu>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menuu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.menuu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.menuu li:hover {
  display: block;
}

.menuu ul li ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menuu>ul>li>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.icerik {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Anasayfa</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">c</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">c1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">a</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Programlama</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Android</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          Java
        </li>
        <li>
          Php
        </li>
        <li>
          Html
        </li>
        <li>
          Css
        </li>
        <li>
          Javascript
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Turizm</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Origami</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Bebek</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Bebeklerin Aylık Gelişimi</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="iletisim.php">İletişim</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="icerik">Önceden İçerik Aşağı kayıyordu email de dediğiniz gibi projeme position absolute ekledim kaymıyor. Teşekkür ederim. Şimdi Tek sorun Bebek Bölümü ve C bölümü üstüne gelince yana kayıyorlar ve yanındakini de kaydırıyorlar</div>
```